# Read and write data to/from Serial Port

Tags: c#, arduino, serial-port, console-application

I am building a console application which will be scheduled in Task Scheduler of Windows to run my code every day at a set hour. Summing up, this application will read and write through `SerialPort`. When I send something to the Arduino, I need to receive something from it to finish up what I've sent and execute the command.

In other words, I will send something so see if the door is opened, if it is the application will run a code to close it. If the door is already closed I will send a bunch of characters to be displayed into the Arduino Led Display.

So I've developed a code but I am not sure if it's totally correct, if possible help me improve it. There is any changes I could make?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerialPort comport = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
    comport.Open();

    string start = "?";
    string carriageReturn = "\r";
    string text = string.Empty;

    string mensage = "@" + "r" + "\r";
    string mensage2 = "@" + "{" + texto + "\r";

    try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                //Send to the Arduino
                comport.Write(start+ "*" + carriageReturn);

                //If the serial port have bytes to read
                if (comport.BytesToRead > 0)
                { 
                    //Buffer with data
                    byte[] dados = HexStringToByteArray(mensage);

                    //Handle data
                    comport.Read(dados, 0, dados.Length);

                    //Send again to execute the the command
                    comport.Write(start + "*" + carriageReturn);
                }

                if (comport.BytesToRead > 0)
                { 
                    comport.Write(start + "*" + carriageReturn);

                    byte[] dados2 = HexStringToByteArray(mensage2);

                    comport.Read(dados2, 0, dados2.Length);

                    comport.Write(text);
                }
                comport.Close();
            }
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
}

private static byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string s)
{
    s = s.Replace(" ", "");
    byte[] buffer = new byte[s.Length / 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i += 2)
        buffer[i / 2] = (byte)Convert.ToByte(s.Substring(i, 2), 16);
        return buffer;
}
```

**EDIT:**

My basic input output mapping/relationship is:

I will send `?*\r` to the Arduino, then I will wait for a answer.

**If** the answer from Arduino is `@r\r` I will send the `?*\r` again.

**If** the answer from the Arduino is `@{/r` I will send a string to him.

Comment: This is off-topic on StackOverflow. To get code reviews, please post your question on [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Already updated the comments....In English. This is Portuguese btw @MongZhu

Comment: why do you fill the `byte[]` and then overwrite it with the values that you read from the `SerialPort` ?

Comment: What I want to do is, send the bytes and according to what I will read I will send again to different bytes @MongZhu

Comment: 1.) "send the bytes and according to what I will read " You seem not to care about what you receive into `dados`. I don't see any condition inspecting the content of it. You always send `inicio + "*" + carriageReturn` irrespective of what you receive. 2. ) your `else` statement is never reached because both `if` conditions are the same. If the first is false, why do you expect the second to be true within the next 5 milli seconds?

Comment: I know that this code isn't well-structured. Basically I have 2 solutions: One of them if send to the Arduino a question and depending on what respond I get I will send 2 different commands. @MongZhu

Comment: I already updated it with some changes that I've made. I don't know if this is right @MongZhu

Comment: Please post your expected input and how you want to react to it. This is fundamental to the understanding of your code. (Basically a mapping of arduino messages to the commands that you want to send)

Comment: @MongZhu I did not developed the Arduino code. I will send "?*\r" to the Arduino, then I will wait for a answer. If the answer from Arduino is "@r\r" I will send the "?*\r" again. If the answer fro the Arduino is "@{/r" I will send a string to him.

Comment: Why do you send twice the same "question" ? Protocol would be easier if all were unique. And why does arduino need an extra command after the "question"?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a first attempt of my revision.

You should consider to use the `DataReceived` event and have an Exit-Strategy. Up to now your program never exits.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM1", 9600, Parity.Odd, 7, StopBits.One);
    // register the event
    port.DataReceived += Port_DataReceived;
    //open the port
    port.Open();

    try
    {
        // start the communication
        port.Write("?*\r");

        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for response");

        // Your manual exit strategy. Hit a kKeyboard-key to end this game
        while (!Console.KeyAvailable)
        {
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Writing failed! \nError: " + ex.Message);
    }        
}
```

The `DataReceived` event will be fired as soon as the Arduino sends you something. If it doesn't you can just quit your program manually.

Inside the event you can do your entire logic. As you already posted the input-output mapping you can just hack it into solid code as it is written in your post. If it is only 2 cases you could also use a switch/case construct:

```
private static void Port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    SerialPort port = sender as SerialPort;

    // read input
    string incoming = port.ReadExisting();

    switch (incoming)
    {
        case "@r\r":
            // send the message back
            port.Write("?*\r");
            break;
        case @"@{/r":
            port.Write("Display this!");
            break;
        default:
            Console.WriteLine("Unknown command from Arduino!\n Command: " + incoming);
            break;
    }
}
```

I hope it helps

Comment: I will study your code and then give you a feed back of what I've got ok?

Comment: I like your code, but this code will run automatically when called by the Task Scheduler and no one will be there to manually click on a key from keyboard. You know?

Comment: ok, then you still should think of a way to exit the program. or it will run forever. That is absolutely up to you. I am glad, that you like my code, if it helped you, you might consider to mark it as answer. :)

Comment: @Forrobodo you should consider using a timer may be, since devices are unreliable and the arduino might decide not to talk to you anymore. Your application will hang in the while loop and never quit. The timer could take care of it. Cancel if no response after X-seconds

Comment: Explain me something. The  `Console.WriteLine("Waiting for response");` will be shown at the console but when the Arduino sent to me something the application will run again?

Comment: So this timer will be next to the `Console.WriteLine("Waiting for response");`?

Comment: as you can see it is like in your application. The while loop is endless. (It is basically waiting for a response and is running endless until you end it (somehow). Whenever arduino sends you something the event will be fired and the code inside will be executed.

Comment: @Forrobodo The Timer would be on it's own thread. You should research a little about [System.Timers.Timer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Forrobodo I thought you want to schedule the application to be restarted each day new?=! You need to take care how and when the application ends.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your description properly (closing the door will be done by arduino, right?), this is the task:

- A task scheduled console app triggers an arduino via Serial to check a status and execute something (if status tells thats necessary)
- Arduino reports back status (and eventually that task was performed)

You could do it very simple:

```
"?" --> PC sends a trigger: Check door status and behave accordingly
```

Then PC waits for a response:

```
"1"  <-- Arduino response ( door was already closed )
"2"  <-- or alternate response ( I closed the door )
```

Arduino could send anything else to indicate an error. (feel free to invent as much as adequate)

Additionally, it's possible that arduino does not respond at all. So what would your scheduled console app do then?

You do not need to send/receive more than a byte, to have it simpler for Arduino and your little Serial PC code.

The PC code does not have a user interface, so there's no need for Arduino to respond immediately, if closing the door should take a while.

Comment: Basically what I am sending is "?*\r" together and the Arduino knows that this command will ask him the status of the door. If the door is opened I will read "@r\r" and send the "?*\r" to close it. If the door status is already closed I will send another thing. You know what I mean?

Comment: So what does "?*\r" mean for the arduino ? A question to respond the door status or a command ? Do you know why I think you make it too complicated?

Comment: No.Tell me then

Comment: Ok, I make my response above a bit more verbose.

Comment: Ok I will wait for it